# How to synchronize wpf richtextbox vertical scrolling with split container Panel2

Tags: c#, winforms

In windows Froms I have a split container in Panle1 I have a WPF richtextbox so I want to synchronize the vertical scrolling of the richtextbox with Panel2 and vis versa. I know how to synchronize scrolling for the Panels.

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap your rich text boxes in a scroll viewer control

```
<ScrollViewer ScrollChanged="ScrollViewer_ScrollChanged_1" Name="scvOriginal">
          <RichTextBox Name="rtbOrginal"   ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" />
</ScrollViewer>

<ScrollViewer Name="scvChanged">
          <RichTextBox Name="rtbChanged" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" />
</ScrollViewer>
```

Then tap into the scroll changed event of the scroll viewer

```
 private void scvOriginal_ScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
 {
     scvChanged.ScrollToVerticalOffset(e.VerticalOffset);
 }
```

This will allow to to set the horizontal and vertical scroll of the 2 rich text boxes.